# Out of every 7 rows, get the nth row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this that's about 1000 rows:

```
      0        1
0  1.345    2.456
1  2.123    3.564
2  0.023    3.548
3  3.457    2.456
4  1.754    3.564
5  0.905    3.548
6  3.674    7.543
7  9.443    6.4433...
```

The way it's organized is every 7 rows constitutes one "set" of data (data cannot be sorted here).  Within each of the "groups" of 7 rows I want to get the first row so my new data frame would look like:

```
      0        1
0  1.345    2.456
7  9.443    6.4433
```

I can solve it by creating a new column that repeats 1-7 & filtering by only that column...

```
      0        1    groupby_col
0  1.345    2.456        1
1  2.123    3.564        2
2  0.023    3.548        3
3  3.457    2.456        4
4  1.754    3.564        5
5  0.905    3.548        6
6  3.674    7.543        7
7  9.443    6.4433       1...
```

then...

```
df[df['groupby_col'] == 1]
```

Is there a way I can do this in pandas without having to create an additional column then filter?

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1:**

```
In [54]: df.iloc[::7]
Out[54]:
       0       1
0  1.345  2.4560
7  9.443  6.4433
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [53]: df.iloc[np.arange(len(df))%7==0]
Out[53]:
       0       1
0  1.345  2.4560
7  9.443  6.4433
```

Comment: Beat me by a minute!  For what it's worth, you could also use df.ix[::7]

Comment: @tnknepp, thank you! `.ix[]` - is deprecated in modern Pandas versions

Comment: No, thank YOU, I was not aware .ix[] is deprecated.  I need to update my pandas.  You have now solved two problems with your post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df.index%7==0]
Out[124]: 
       0       1
0  1.345  2.4560
7  9.443  6.4433
```

Or

```
df.groupby(df.index//7,as_index=False).first()
Out[128]: 
       0       1
0  1.345  2.4560
1  9.443  6.4433
```

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing it.  While it works for the OP's example, it will not work if the index is not monotonically increasing from 0.  Still, interesting.

Comment: using `groupby` - is very fresh and unusual approach ! +1

Comment: @MaxU I do not want to using `groupby` LOL... but it is hard think outside your box :-)

Comment: You can also use `.nth(<whatever>)` with the group-by, more flexible if this will be generalized

Comment: I did a quick test using a dataframe with 1E7 rows and 5 columns.  The .iloc method proposed by MaxU took 0.001s, while Wen's .groupby method took 1.5s (1,500x longer).  This makes sense given the additional overhead...just an FYI.